# getting issue in text not in proper line

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

mean when whenever I add an address if the address is one it's working fine but if a get a large address it's going in second-line its ok but first like move-in upside its looks bad you can see the image for proper understanding.
how can set if address gets increase then first like not get in up line?

CSS

```
.td-width tr td:first-child{
  width: 100px;
}
.table-bottom{
  margin-bottom: -1.5%;
  /* border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray; */
}
.table-top{
  margin-top: -2%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables by default vertically center the content. You can change that by changing the `vertical-align` property:

```css
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```